# What is ().__class__.__base__.__subclasses__()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, sandbox, built-in

I was attempting a Python Sandbox Escape challenge (***Python 3.8.10***) and it had builtins disabled:

`exec(command, {'__builtins__': None, 'print':print}`

There was also a filter that the input went through that blacklisted the usage of `'` , `"` and `` ` ``

Due to these rules, I saw many people using `().__class__.__base__.__subclasses__()` and it returned a list of classes. They called these classes using their index value in the list.

For example:

`print(().__class__.__base__.__subclasses__()[4])`

would return something like

`<class 'int'>`

Why does `().__class__.__base__.__subclasses__()` work in this case and why does this command have to be in this specific order?

Comment: It would be more instructive to bring up Python and see what each step does.  `().__class__` returns the `tuple` class.  Calling `.__base__` on that returns the `object` class.  The `.__subclasses__` method returns all the subclasses of type `object`.  The 4th entry in that list happens to be `int`.  When in doubt, try it.

Comment: @TimRoberts yes I did try each and every one of them step by step. However, I did not know what each of them meant and what they were called. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Piece by piece:

- `()` - The empty `tuple`
- `().__class__` - The `tuple` class
- `().__class__.__base__` - The `object` class (the ultimate base class of *all* classes is `object`)
- `().__class__.__base__.__subclasses__()` - The `__subclasses__` method returns a `list` of all the immediate subclasses of the class it is called on; for `object`, that means all classes with no other explicit parent class.

The reason they're using this technique is that, with all builtin *names* disabled, `()` is still an object literal they can use to gain access to most of them.

If you did it in any other order, you'd get gibberish as a result; all the attributes save `__class__` only exist on classes, so calling them on `tuple` itself would be nonsensical. Failing to go to `__base__` before calling `__subclasses__()` would only get you the immediate subclasses of `tuple` (possibly useful, as it includes all the named tuple types, both C level and Python level, in a program, but it wouldn't include stuff like `int`).

The only part that can be trivially swapped out is the `()`; *any* legal Python object that is an instance of an immediate subclass of `object` would work equivalently here (which I believe includes all types with literal syntax), so `""`, or `1.` (not `1` alone unless you put a space after it or wrap it in parentheses, as the method call `.` would make it a `float` literal, and without a second `.`, you'd get a `SyntaxError`), or `[]`, or `{}` or whatever would all work equally well. The only real advantage to `()` is that it's a short name that's a singleton, so it's slightly more efficient than most of the other options, both in keystrokes and in runtime performance. Given the restrictions on `'`, `"` and `\`, `()` and various numeric literals would be the only literals competitive with `().__class__` (assuming zero values for each numeric type are singletons; not a language guarantee, but a common optimization).

Comment: Immaculate explanation. I did not know why they used parentheses and that if I could use something other than parentheses to make it work the same way. Thank you!